# python websocket fetch returns empty object

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the pybit package (https://github.com/verata-veritatis/pybit) on a crypto exchange, but when i try to fetch the data from the websocket, all I get is an empty object as a response.

```
import pybit


endpoint_public = 'wss://stream.bybit.com/realtime_public'

subs = [
    'orderBookL2_25.BTCUSD',
    'instrument_info.100ms.BTCUSD',
    'last_price.BTCUSD'
]

ws_unauth = WebSocket(endpoint_public, subscriptions=subs)


ws_unauth.fetch('last_price.BTCUSD')
```

the output is this

```
{}
```

Comment: I don't know this modyle but usually websocket runs some "event loop" which will wait for response and run callback when it get new data?

Comment: maybe this need to use `API KEY` to get any data.

Comment: I don't see `'last_price.BTCUSD'` in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: 2022.09.19**

It seems they changed code in module and examples in documentation are different. They don't use `fetch()` but they assign subscription to functions - `handlers` - and websocket runs own (hidden) loop to fetch data and execute assigned function.

---

I found three problems:

**First:** code works for me if I use endpoint `realtime` instead of `realtime_public` - I found it in somewhere in [ByBit API documentation](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-introduction) (not in documentation for Python module)

**Second:** there is no `'last_price.BTCUSD'` in documentation - and this generate errors when I try it with endpoint `realtime` - and other subscriptions don't work.

**Third:** first `fetch` may not give result and it may need to `sleep()` short time before first `fetch`. Normally code should run in some loop and get data every few (milli)seconds and then it makes no problem. You could also use `if` to run some code only if you get data.

```
import pybit
import time

endpoint_public = 'wss://stream.bybit.com/realtime'

subs = [
    'orderBookL2_25.BTCUSD',
    'instrument_info.100ms.BTCUSD',
#    'last_price.BTCUSD'
]

ws_unauth = pybit.WebSocket(endpoint_public, subscriptions=subs)
time.sleep(1)

#print(ws_unauth.fetch('last_price.BTCUSD'))    # doesn't work with `realtime_public`; generate error with `realtime`  
print(ws_unauth.fetch('orderBookL2_25.BTCUSD')) # doesn't work with `realtime_public`; works with `realtime`
```

Result:

```
[
  {'price': '40702.50', 'symbol': 'BTCUSD', 'id': 407025000, 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 350009}, 
  {'price': '40703.00', 'symbol': 'BTCUSD', 'id': 407030000, 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 10069}, 
  {'price': '40705.00', 'symbol': 'BTCUSD', 'id': 407050000, 'side': 'Buy', 'size': 28}, 
  # ...
]
```

---

**BTW:**

`ByBit API Documentation` shows also examples for [Public Topic](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-websocketorderbook25).

They use:

- `realtime` instead of `realtime_public`,
- loop to fetch data periodically,
- `if data` to skip empty response.

```
from pybit import WebSocket
subs = [
    "orderBookL2_25.BTCUSD"
]
ws = WebSocket(
    "wss://stream-testnet.bybit.com/realtime",
    subscriptions=subs
)
while True:
    data = ws.fetch(subs[0])
    if data:
        print(data)
```

`ByBit API Documentation` shows also examples for [Private Topic](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-websocketposition).

They also use:

- `realtime` instead of `realtime_public` ( + `api_key`, `api_secret`),
- loop to fetch data periodically,
- `if data` to skip empty response.

For test they use `stream-testnet` but in real code it should use `stream`.

Comment: How would you handle a disconnection in this While loop ?

Comment: @PieroCosta if it raises error then I would put `fetch()` and `if data:` in `try/except` and inside `except` I would use again `ws = WebSocket(...)`

Comment: @PieroCosta it seems they changed code in module and examples in documentation are different - they don't use `fetch()` but they assign subscription to functions - `handlers` and websocket runs own (hidden) loop to fetch data and execute assigned function.